# Why can't top find my python processes on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, top

I am running a Kubuntu (ubuntu), and I executed two command-line apps through the terminal. My user is 'martin'. In the 'top' window, i can't see my python3 processes:

```
python3 command-line-1
python3 command-line-2
```

Please see the attach file.

[image]

Comment: For a start try `top -u martin` to only have your processes...

Comment: It displays a lot more processes by martin, but still didn't show the 'python' processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you can get them using

```
ps -af | grep python3
```

Otherwise if the python code uses one of the `os.exec*()` calls, the same process continues but runs the exec'ed command which is the one you will see in `top` or `ps`. You can confirm this like this:

1. Start the command as a background process and recover its pid

   ```
   python3 [whatever}  & echo Python3 started as PID: $!
   ```
2. Use `ps` with the PID you obtained:

   ```
   ps -p $pid
   ```

With some luck you can even catch it "morphing":

```
#! /bin/bash

python3 {whatever} & pid=$!
for i in {1..10}
do
    ps -p $pid || exit 1
    sleep .2  # adjust for speed
done
```